# Socket or websocket for financial application with high frequency

Tags: .net, sockets, websocket

> **EDIT by Myst**: Please see a duplicate question with a lengthly answer given by @jfriend00 here: **[advantage WebSockets over TCP/IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781890/advantage-websockets-over-tcp-ip)**

I need create a trading application in Clients (WPF) / Server (.NET).
I dont know what is the best between Socket and Websocket in my case.

Websocket is actually the most use, it's easyest and they are a lot of framework as:

- SuperWebSocket
- PowerWebSockets
- XSockets

but I why use Websocket if socket can do this ?
I have no web application, only desktop.
I love the idea of WebRPC and I dislike the anti-pattern

```
void onMesage (imessage m)
{
   switch(m.MessageObject)
     case "A": DoA(); Break ;
     case "B": DoB(); Break ;
     case "C": DoC(); Break ;
}
```

With on socket/websocket by client I need dispatch message to the good component.

I dont know if websocket is a good choice for trading application (performance with a lot of messages ticker price).

Do you know this Framework ?
Do you think socket is more appropriate ?

thanks

Comment: It is a vague question as you ask for an advice that not a generic site like SO can support. For trading things it has its own requirements and regulation, so either to use or not to use a technology you are bind to more factors than the general public. Though protocols such as WebSocket/QUIC might be the options.

Comment: Since this is put on hold I cant answer. However, I know alot about WebSockets and (Sockets) and will be happy to help you out. I would NOT go for WebSockets. I would use a custom socket protocol. The important things for you is probably strongly typed model binding and routing so that you avoid the "switch/case hell" you described above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

WebSockets are full duplex persistent connections. WebSocket has its own data framing protocol that is very lightweight, so even if you go with raw sockets, you will have to implement your own. Also, WebSocket connections starts as HTTP requests, so that made them friendly to firewalls and load balancers.

However, WebSocket is just a transport technology. If you want a message broker to route messages to the right clients, I recommend you to set up a proper framework for that and use WebSockets just for connecting to it. If you need something for high performance and no need for persistence, probably http://zeromq.org/ is a good option.

Basically, you would use WebSockets to put messages in and out of the message broker queues, and then let the message broker framework to route messages to the right places.

Also, I develop a WebSocket component myself for .NET and Mono named [WebSocketListener](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/). It [scales well](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/WebSocketListener-performance-tests), you should give it a try.